# Ruby on Rails missing nokogiri /nokogiri

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I'm doing a tutorial on Ruby on Rails from Lynda, and everything has gone the way it should. All installations and everything has worked flawless.

But after creating a project, when I try to start the server (cmd: rails server) I get the error message:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri
```

I have 
* Windows 7 x64
* Rails 4.2.4, 
* Gem 2.4.8.

I'm in the directory of the project. All files are there, everything looks ok. I created my project like this: `ruby new test_cms` and I also tried this: `ruby new my_cms -d mysql` . Same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you runned `bundle install`?

Comment: @YuryLebedev Yes. And no problem there

Comment: Are you sure there were no errors there? Because nokogiri requires libxml2, which i suppose is not present on windows os

Comment: @YuryLebedev There is no error message when running bundle install. It says: "Bunlde complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed"

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though nokogiri isn't be loaded, so you need it. So first think to do is check that it is in your Gemfile.  If it is - move it to the top (I know - strange but it sometimes sorts out similar issues). If it's not, add it:

```
  gem 'nokogiri'
```

Then run `bundle install` again.

Then try running `bundle exec rails server` to run the server with your bundle. You may be running it out of context.

Comment: Thank you. There was no nokogiri in my gem file. Added that and ran bundle and the bundle exec command. Same result "no nokogiri/nokogiri". In my bundle install message it says "using nokogii 1.6.6.2

Answer (score 0):

If 'nokogirl' is located in your Gemfile maybe try updating your gems. try `$ gem update --system`.